# Sidekiq WebUI stops showing workers after period of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I have several different Sidekiq tasks that are long running tasks.  These tasks are made to be started, and (almost) never stop.  What I am seeing is that after a period of time my tasks are no longer displaying in the Sidekiq Web UI:

[image]

However, doing a quick `ps -aux | grep 'sidekiq'` shows [2 of 25] workers busy.

I have indeed validated that these workers are correctly processing still (they are still correctly performing their jobs).  However, I am concerned that they are no longer showing up in the Sidekiq Web UI.

Last entries in my Sidekiq log:

```
2014-03-24T00:52:56Z 8182 TID-9b05k INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.17.7 with redis options {}
2014-03-24T00:52:56Z 8182 TID-9b05k INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]
2014-03-24T00:52:56Z 8182 TID-9b05k INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2014-03-24T00:52:56Z 8182 TID-13yaac TwitterImpressionScraper JID-23efa55960f936eb4f815f46 INFO: start
2014-03-24T00:52:56Z 8182 TID-13yaac TwitterImpressionScraper JID-23efa55960f936eb4f815f46 INFO: Started TwitterImpressionScraper Job for App ID: 4
2014-03-24T00:52:56Z 8182 TID-or3tralq8 TwitterImpressionScraper JID-58953c177698cee6ae593587 INFO: start
2014-03-24T00:52:56Z 8182 TID-or3tralq8 TwitterImpressionScraper JID-58953c177698cee6ae593587 INFO: Started TwitterImpressionScraper Job for App ID: 5
```

Comment: Several issues reported like this and seems like caused by redis latency. [1891](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1891) [1963](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1963)

Comment: You can remove all jobs by using FLUSHALL in redis (redis-cli)

Comment: FLUSHALL will delete all keys, if he's using redis for other issues probably it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've observed on multiple occasions also. However, as you have also discovered, it seems to only be an issue with the UI, and not with the workers themselves.

Although it is perhaps a matter of taste, I wouldn't consider sidekiq to be the correct solution for a process that is started and is never meant to stop.

That is not really a job (a fixed amount of work), it probably just better being a normal ruby process... so perhaps the fact that Sidekiq UI is bugging out on monitoring your long running job is trying to tell you something?